# EF Core doesn't create child entities sequentially

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I use JSON string to create entities.

The server converts the json string then add them to context.

After calling Context.SaveChanges(), Data is saved correctly.

But children sequences are mixed up after that.

I don't know why they aren't saved sequentially.

[Models]

```cs
  public class Parent
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("ImageFileId")] // This model is used for storing image files.
     public ImageFile ImageFile { get; set; } 
     public int ImageFileId { get; set; }
  }

  public class Child
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
     public Parent Parent { get; set; }
     public int ParentId { get; set; }
  }
```

[Controller]

```cs
  [ApiController]
  [Route("api")]
  public class ApiController : Controller
  {
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] CreateDTO param)
    {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
      }

      var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
      {
          PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
      };

      var entity = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Parent>(param.Parent, options);

      // The Parent object has children sequentially here.

      _context.Parents.Add(entity);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // After this, Data aren't saved sequentially in the database.

      // ...
    }
  }

  // ...

  public class CreateDTO
  {
     public string Parent { get; set; }
     public IFormFile[] Files { get; set; }
  }
```

[Post Data]

```json
{
  parent: {
    name: "Parent Name",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Child 1"
      },
      {
        name: "Child 2"
      },
      {
        name: "Child 3"
      },
      {
        name: "Child 4"
      },
      {
        name: "Child 5"
      },
      {
        name: "Child 6"
      },
      {
        name: "Child 7"
      },
      {
        name: "Child 8"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[Saved Data] (It's not saved as json data in database. I've just express it like json here)

```js
{
  Parent: {
    Id: 1,
    Name: "Parent Name",
    ImageFileId: 1,
    Children: [
      {
        Id: 1,
        Name: "Child 1",
        ParentId: 1,
      },
      {
        Id: 2,
        Name: "Child 4",
        ParentId: 1,
      },
      {
        Id: 3,
        Name: "Child 3",
        ParentId: 1,
      },
      {
        Id: 4,
        Name: "Child 8",
        ParentId: 1,
      },
      {
        Id: 5,
        Name: "Child 5",
        ParentId: 1,
      },
      {
        Id: 6,
        Name: "Child 2",
        ParentId: 1,
      },
      {
        Id: 7,
        Name: "Child 7",
        ParentId: 1,
      },
      {
        Id: 8,
        Name: "Child 6",
        ParentId: 1,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I am wondering what a difference it make?

Comment: Order. I want them to be created sequentially by collection index

Comment: Since EF uses async you will never get it. The only way you  have to save them one after another.

Comment: Ahh... Can't I control model sequence?

Comment: Hi @seongkukhan, what is your version of ef core? I have test your code by using ef core 5.0.1 and it works in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the best way to keep sequence is to add OrderNum field to a Children

but if you want to save the same sequence of children using id value, try this

```
 var entity = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Parent>(param.Parent, options);
 var children=entity.Children;
 entity.Children=null;

  _context.Parents.Add(entity);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

foreach( var child in children)
{
         child.ParentId=entity.Id;
         _context.Children.Add(child);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I am not sure how much the performance will drop, but if the sequence is more important, you can try.